# List created in OnInit not persisting

Tags: c#, asp.net

I having a problem maintaining a list of strings. The list is instantiated in OnInit and set as the data source for a `GridView`. (The basic idea is that the user enters something in the text box, and it appears in the `GridView`, as many times as they want.)

It works just fine for the first entry, whatever the user enters shows up in the `GridView`, pretty as can be. However, on following entries, any previously entered values disappear - `OnInit` is executed again, the `List<string>` is re-instantiated, and the previous values are over-written. I tried moving the `OnInit` logic into `OnPreInit` but just got a Null Reference Exception on the list.

Here's a contrived example of what I'm trying to do:

I have a `TextBox`, a `Button` and a `Gridview`:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add"
     onclick="Button1_Click" />
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
    AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>
```

In the code behind:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> gvValues = new List<string>();
    GridView1.DataSource = gvValues;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     gvValues.Add(TextBox1.Text);
     GridView1.DataBind();
}
```

I've created objects in `OnInit` in the past, and haven't had a problem with their state persisting. Obviously I'm missing something here. Someone please point out the flaw in my logic and suggest a method for achieving this functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code is tested an it works.

```
// ASPX Code
<asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Add"
 onclick="Button1_Click" />
 <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"
AutoGenerateColumns="true"></asp:GridView>

// Code Behind
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> gvValues = new List<string>();
        GridView1.DataSource = gvValues;
        GridView1.DataBind();
        Session["Data"] = gvValues;
    }
}
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> lt = new List<string>();
    lt = (List<String>)Session["Data"];
    lt.Add(TextBox1.Text);
    GridView1.DataSource = lt;
    GridView1.DataBind();
    Session["Data"] = lt; // Save it in Session, so next time available
}

// Add the values one by one, and it will show you all the values
// OUTPUT
  Test
  Test1
  Test2
```

Comment: Tried this in `Page_Load` and `OnInit`, it just causes a Null Reference Exception.

Comment: Cool, this worked. I'll accept in a little bit, but I want to see if there are any other solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to reassign the list to the gridview and put the gvValues into the session:

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
{
    GridView1.DataSource = GvValues;
    GridView1.DataBind();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     GvValues.Add(TextBox1.Text);
     GridView1.DataSource = GvValues;
     GridView1.DataBind();
}

private List<string> GvValues
{
  get
  {
    if(Session["list"] != null)
    {
      return (List<string>)Session["list"];
    }

     return new List<string>();
  }

  set
  {
    Session["list"] value;
  }
}
```

Comment: Add wait you have to make gvValues global, I will edit my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I did a small example which worked fine for me

**default.aspx**

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
    <asp:GridView ID="gvEntries" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true">
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtNewEntry" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
    <asp:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save entry" OnClick="btnSave_Click" />
</form>
```

**default.aspx.cs**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        List<string> source = new List<string>();
        source.Add("entry1");
        source.Add("entry2");
        source.Add("entry3");
        Session["source"] = source;
        gvEntries.DataSource = source;
        gvEntries.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    List<string> source = (List<string>)Session["source"];
    source.Add(txtNewEntry.Text);
    gvEntries.DataSource = source;
    gvEntries.DataBind();
}
```

This example *binds* your *initial data on pageLoad* (GET). So your datasource is stored within the gridviews viewstate. If you want to add another entry you *have to access your original source* - which has been ***stored within a Session-var***. So get a reference to it, add a value, and rebind your dataSource.